# Update jquery flot with datepicker from json php

Tags: php, jquery, json, datepicker, flot

Script is returning correct `json_encode` array from php file based on selected datepicker range from - to date but only to div `#results`.

How can I use this `json_encode #results` data to plot jquery flot?

```
$(function () {
    function updateResults() {
        // Load response from results.php into #results element
        $('#results').load('results.php', 
        { // With these parameters
            from_date: fromDate.datepicker('getDate').toString(),
            to_date: toDate.datepicker('getDate').toString()
        });
    }

    //create a couple of date textboxes
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        defaultDate: '-1w',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: 0,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showWeek: true
    });

    var fromDate = $('#from').datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            var option = this.id == 'from' ? 'minDate' : 'maxDate';
            toDate.not(this).datepicker('option', option, $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
            updateResults(); // When a new date is selected update the results
        }
    });

    var toDate = $('#to').datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            updateResults(); // When a new date is selected update the results
        }
    });

    //Set the default from and to dates.
    fromDate.datepicker('setDate', '-1w');
    toDate.datepicker('setDate', '+0');
    updateResults(); // Initial call on load
});
```

Comment: How does the result from `results.php` look like? Is it JSON? (In the right format for flot?) Is it HTML?

Comment: results.php is $_POST which uses from_date and to_date for mysql query and outputs echo json_encode with data in selected range. It's not in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The `load()` function is for loading HTML into your DOM elements. To load JSON data use the `jQuery.getJSON()` function like this:

```
function updateResults() {
    $.getJSON('results.php', {
        from_date: fromDate.datepicker('getDate').toString(),
        to_date: toDate.datepicker('getDate').toString()
    }, function(data, status, xhr) {
        $.plot('#results', [data], options);
    });
}
```

This assumes that `data` is in the right format for flot.

Comment: Where should I put this function to retrieve data based on datepicker range select?

Comment: In your `updateResults()` function, it replaces the old code with the `load()` function. See my edit.

Comment: Now I'm getting time on xaxis just 1.1.1970. I think JSON is ok: [[1431468001000,15.8],[1431468301000,15.8],[1431468601000,15.8]]

Comment: Looks ok. To say more I would have to see the data / code in more detail, for example as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Strange thing. If I put displayed JSON in json_encode it shows in flot perfect but when it is pulled from mysql query to json_encode it just doesn't show and date is always 1.1.1970. echo json_encode(array($dataset),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); echo json_encode(array([[1431554402000,16.6],[1431554701000,16.6]]), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); But if I just display array on screen it is same.

Comment: You could try calling `JSON.parse()` on your array.

Comment: If I JSON.parse on array: var dataset = JSON.parse(data[0]); same thing empty flot with 1.1.1970.

Comment: Problem is with datepicker posting format: Wed May 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST). Any idea how can I change this format in my function to 2015-05-20 so it is ready for mysql query?

Comment: I used this in PHP file:  $from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(preg_replace('/\s\(.*$/', '', $from))); and works. Also jQuery.getJSON() function uses $_GET and not $_POST to php file.

Answer (score 0):

check that the unix/mysql timedata *1000 -> flot x-axis time?
Flot needs milliseconds time data